# How To Insert Data Using Multiple Input With Same Name in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm using JavaScript would produce the following entries

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_img[]" value="dad6e52b274690409835.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="my_img[]" value="252529b6e21f872c7675.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="my_img[]" value="3cce4128c366216fsfaf.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="my_img[]" value="48697e8516caa3cc15d4.jpg">
```

But I've had trouble inserting them in the database

my controllers :

```
   $dd=$this->input->post('my_img');
   for($i=0;$i<count($dd);$i++)
   {
   $img_box[$i] = array ('img_url' => $dd[$i]);
   }
   $this->posts_model->add_new_ads_img($img_box);
```

my model :

```
public function add_new_ads_img($img_box)
{
    $q = $this->db->insert('advertise_gallery',$img_box);
    if ($q)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else return FALSE;
}
```

And to eat error

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: img_box

Please guide me

Comment: $img_box only lives within the for loop scope. Define it outside of the loop like this: $img_box = array();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error could be this line in your controller:

```
$img_box[$i] = array ('img_url' => $dd[$i]);
```

Just before your for-loop add:

```
$img_box = [];
```

Comment: I think newer versions of php prefer = array() over = [] (not that it matters too much for this question)

Comment: Only newer versions support `[]`, previously you had to use `array()`. (Since 5.4 I think)

Comment: Ah that makes sense.

Comment: tnx fix it 
but now have other problem 
i have 10 input but i 
print_r($img_box);

show >>> arry() is empty
and
echo count($dd)
show  >>> 0

Comment: If `count($dd)` === 0, it seems that you did not post your page. If you comment out your code controller code except for the `$dd=$this->input->post('my_img');`, is the count different?

Comment: As a side note: when inserting multiple rows at once, you should probably use [`insert_batch`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::insert_batch) instead of `insert`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I think you are trying to do, you could try to give each input a different id. That way you could insert based on the id name.

for exampe:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="my_img[]" id="img1" value="dad6e52b274690409835.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="my_img[]" id = "img2" value="252529b6e21f872c7675.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="my_img[]" id = "img3" value="3cce4128c366216fsfaf.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="my_img[]" id = "img4" value="48697e8516caa3cc15d4.jpg">
```

if you need to add them to an array, you can do so in the java script

```
var img=[$('#img1').val(),$('#img2').val(),$('#img3').val()]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No
I want all entries are sent with a one name